# Getting Data from Previous VIew Controller

Tags: delegates, swift2, segue, viewcontroller, message-passing

I am trying to get values from my last view controller. I have a TextField in my last views and I want that text to carry on in my next view controller. Suppose if I write "5" in the TextField, I want that to display on a label in my next view. Is this possible, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called `prepareForSegue()` where you take all the information you need and send it to the next ViewController

Answer (score 2):

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as! YOUR_CONTROLLER

//Setup the properties
vc.PROPERTY = "DATA"   //this property variable has to be there in your destination view controller

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or else you can use `prepareForSegue:`